# Sort a map of objects with multiple fields using a comparator

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have an `Author` object with `name`, `age`, and `index` fields.  The Authors are stored in a HashMap (the key is the index).

I would like to be able to sort by name and age.

This begins a method I want to put in my Author class but clearly I am not understanding this:

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, Author> sortName(Map<String, Author> unSortedMap){

    Collection<Author> list = unSortedMap.values();

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Author>() {
        public int compare(Author a, Author b) {
            return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
        }
});
}
```

It won't compile because of this: (from Eclipse)

`The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<Author>, new Comparator<Author>(){})`

1. The Collections class fields are EMPTY_LIST, EMPTY_MAP, and EMPTY_SET.  Why can't the sort method pass a Map with a Comparator?
2. I thought `<T>` was generic so I could pass any kind of object I wanted.
3. Am I correct that if this worked, Collections.sort() would sort `list` by the Author's name?  So I would end up with a `LinkedList<Author>` that I could turn into a `LinkedHashMap<String, Author>` and send on it's way?

Thank you in advance.  Clearly I'm student.  I've also searched for HOURS for information that could guide me toward a solution.  I've read every question re: "Collections sort multiple values comparator".  Nothing is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't compile because `Collections.sort()` only sorts *`Lists`*, not *`Collections`*.

If you want to sort the values, it's east to turn a Collection into a List by passing the collection into the constructor of the List:

```
List<Author> list = new ArrayList<Author>(unSortedMap.values());

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Author>() {
    public int compare(Author a, Author b) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    }
});
```

But that won't get the job done. Instead, you need to sort the `Map`'s *`Entry`* objects, then put them into the map:

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, Author> sortName(Map<String, Author> unSortedMap) {
    List<Map.Entry<String, Author>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Author>>(unSortedMap.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Author>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Author> a, Map.Entry<String, Author> b) {
            return a.getValue().name.compareTo(b.getValue().name);
        }
    });

    LinkedHashMap<String, Author> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Author>();
    for (Entry<String, Author> entry : list) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  So an Entry object is the key and value together?  If the sort is passing only a list of Authors, why would the compare need the Entry?  Unless the .values() method isn't doing what I think it is (simply creating a list of Authors)